# Different props state for smart and dumb component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a dumb React component which receives a bunch of parameters, where several of them are funcs.

```
const ProfileForm = (user, markers, onChange, onCheckBoxChange) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <TextInput name={'firstname'} label={'First name: '} value={user.firstname} onChange={onChange}/>
      <TextInput name={'lastname'} label={'Last name: '} value={user.lastname} onChange={onChange}/>
      <TextInput name={'phone'} label={'Phone: '} value={user.phone} onChange={onChange}/>
      <div>
        As who you want to be presented on a map:
        <CheckBoxInput name={"type"} label={"Driver"} value={Constants.TYPE_DRIVER} checked={markers.driver} onChange={onCheckBoxChange}/>
        <CheckBoxInput name={"type"} label={"Passenger"} value={Constants.TYPE_PASSENGER} checked={markers.passenger} onChange={onCheckBoxChange}/>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Apparently PropTypes module which I didn't paste here tells me that `onChange` parameter supposed to be a func but is an object. I checked in debugger and indeed it is some strange object which I didn't pass.

Well, than I changed my component into smart one, without changing anything else and it works now! Am I missing something?

```
class ProfileForm extends React.Component {

  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <TextInput name={'firstname'} label={'First name: '} value={this.props.user.firstname} onChange={this.props.onChange}/>
        <TextInput name={'lastname'} label={'Last name: '} value={this.props.user.lastname} onChange={this.props.onChange}/>
        <TextInput name={'phone'} label={'Phone: '} value={this.props.user.phone} onChange={this.props.onChange}/>
        <div>
          As who you want to be presented on a map:
          <CheckBoxInput name={"type"} label={"Driver"} value={Constants.TYPE_DRIVER} checked={!!this.props.markers.driver} onChange={this.props.onCheckBoxChange}/>
          <CheckBoxInput name={"type"} label={"Passenger"} value={Constants.TYPE_PASSENGER} checked={!!this.props.markers.passenger} onChange={this.props.onCheckBoxChange}/>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are missing the object destructuring of props in the functional component

```
const ProfileForm = ({user, markers, onChange, onCheckBoxChange}) => {
 // its important because functional component takes a single argument. but with ES6 you can always destructure it

 return (
    <div>
      <TextInput name={'firstname'} label={'First name: '} value={user.firstname} onChange={onChange}/>
      <TextInput name={'lastname'} label={'Last name: '} value={user.lastname} onChange={onChange}/>
      <TextInput name={'phone'} label={'Phone: '} value={user.phone} onChange={onChange}/>
      <div>
        As who you want to be presented on a map:
        <CheckBoxInput name={"type"} label={"Driver"} value={Constants.TYPE_DRIVER} checked={markers.driver} onChange={onCheckBoxChange}/>
        <CheckBoxInput name={"type"} label={"Passenger"} value={Constants.TYPE_PASSENGER} checked={markers.passenger} onChange={onCheckBoxChange}/>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

OR you can try with single argument also

```
const ProfileForm = (props) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <TextInput name={'firstname'} label={'First name: '} value={props.user.firstname} onChange={props.onChange}/>
      <TextInput name={'lastname'} label={'Last name: '} value={props.user.lastname} onChange={props.onChange}/>
      <TextInput name={'phone'} label={'Phone: '} value={props.user.phone} onChange={props.onChange}/>
      <div>
        As who you want to be presented on a map:
        <CheckBoxInput name={"type"} label={"Driver"} value={Constants.TYPE_DRIVER} checked={props.markers.driver} onChange={props.onCheckBoxChange}/>
        <CheckBoxInput name={"type"} label={"Passenger"} value={Constants.TYPE_PASSENGER} checked={props.markers.passenger} onChange={props.onCheckBoxChange}/>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

your Class component is working because you are passing the correct props there.

Answer (score 1):

Dumb "function" components take in a single argument of `props`.  They do not take in a series of arguments.  I mean, think about it.... how would this:

```
<ProfileForm user={user} onChange={onChange}/>
```

be able to be parsed into this:

```
ProfileForm(user, undefined, onChange, undefined)
```

It can't!

So instead, it calls as such:

```
ProfileForm({user:user, onChange:onChange})
```

And you can reference in the same fashion in your function definition;

```
const ProfileForm = ({user, markers, onChange, onCheckBoxChange}) => {
```